# In Django Rest, not able to serialize object which has One-to-Many mapping

Tags: python, python-2.7, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am beginner in Django Rest framework. I want to implement One to Many object mapping like following json schema:

```
{
  "from_date": "2017-08-06T12:30",
  "to_date": "2017-08-06T12:30",
  "coupon_name": "WELCOME100",
  "min_booking_value": 150,
  "applicable_days": [
    {
      "from_time": "13:00",
      "to_time": "15:00",
      "applicable_day": 2
    },
    {
      "from_time": "16:00",
      "to_time": "18:00",
      "applicable_day": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

For above json schema, I have created following Django Model classes:

```
class Coupon(models.Model):
    coupon_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    from_date = models.DateTimeField()
    to_date = models.DateTimeField()
    coupon_name = models.TextField()
    min_booking_value = models.FloatField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return 'Coupon id: ' + str(self.coupon_id)


class CouponApplicableDays(models.Model):
    from_time = models.TimeField()
    to_time = models.TimeField()
    applicable_day = models.IntegerField()
```

And following serializer class above models:

```
class CouponApplicableDaysSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CouponApplicableDays
        fields = ('from_time', 'to_time', 'applicable_day')


class CouponSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    coupon_applicable_days = CouponApplicableDaysSerializer(required=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Coupon
        fields = ('coupon_id', 'from_date', 'to_date', 'coupon_name', 'min_booking_value', 'coupon_applicable_days',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        coupon_applicable_days_data = validated_data.pop("coupon_applicable_days")
        coupon = Coupon.objects.create(**validated_data)
        CouponApplicableDays.objects.create(coupon=coupon, **coupon_applicable_days_data)
        return coupon
```

When I save data using coupon-serializer. It saves only in Coupon table not in CouponApplicableDays.

I know, I have messed up somewhere but I don't know where. Can you guys please look into above code and tell me how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a list here 
`coupon_applicable_days_data = validated_data.pop("coupon_applicable_days")`

Either iterate over the list and create the objects, like this:

```
for applicable_day in coupon_applicable_days_data: 
    CouponApplicableDays.objects.create(coupon=coupon, **applicable_day)
```

or use the `bulk_create` method
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create

```
CouponApplicableDays.objects.bulk_create(
    [CouponApplicableDays(coupon=coupon, **aplicable_day)
     for applicable_day in coupon_applicable_days_data]
)
```

Be aware that the `bulk_create` will not trigger `pre_save/post_save` signals.